# How many people can a zombie kill, and who's first?

Tags: die2nite

If the town defense is not adequate (or somebody forgot to lock the door) some zombies may enter the town at midnight.

How does it calculates how many people will be killed by the zombies? And who is killed first, the people with the lowest defense value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The zombies that make it through the defense are randomly distributed to each citizen.
2. If the citizen's *house defense value* is lower than the zombies assigned to him, he dies.
3. The order of the attacks is random.

Comment: I'd like to add that it can also happen that way more zombies attack someone than is needed to kill them. The algorithm doesn't seem to say "Oh, there's already enough zombies assigned to this guy to kill him, let's stop remove him from the pool of random people zombies can attack." As such, even if enough zombies get in to kill everyone in town, there still might be some survivors due to the random nature of assigning attacks.

Comment: It sounds like the way this is resolved is different now, but I haven't found details of the exact mechanism.